# Laravel - Populate Select Box with other select box based on selected data

Tags: html, laravel-5

My database

make_models
models_id   make_id
1            1
4            1
10           1
11           2
17           2
makes
1
2
models
1
4
10
11
17

Controller

```
$makes=make::all();
$models=models::all();
return view('admin.vehicles.create',compact('makes','models'));
```

create.blade.php
for makes

```
<select class="form-control">
   @foreach($makes as $make)
       <option value="{{ $make->id}}">{{ $make->name}}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

Model

```
public function makes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\Make','make_models')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

this is like category and subcategory but i cant follow